# Using LIKE against a integer

Tags: php, sql, integer, sql-like

I'm trying to do a `LIKE` search against NumberID's that are stored as a INTEGER. Can I easily edit code I use to search against a varchar to also search against integer?

```
$sql .= " WHERE NumberID LIKE '%$search_term%'";
```

The search_term is taken from a PHP box the user can use to enter information to search against. Ideally I would like to avoid changing the database from a integer at the moment.

Comment: Is `$search_term` escaped ? You should be careful with mysql injections.

Comment: What result do you expect to get?

Comment: Using `LIKE` against an integer is highly suspicious.  You seem to have a problem with your data model.

Comment: maybe you should look at bitwise operators instead...

Comment: If you received an answer, that you think is the best soltuion to your problem, you may [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Answer (score 0):

You current code should actually work as is, though technically speaking you should first cast your integer to text before building the `LIKE` expression:

```
WHERE NumberID LIKE CONCAT('%', CAST(? AS CHAR(50)), '%')
```

To the `?` placeholder you would then bind your integer variable `$search_term`.

Answer (score 0):

This does the job :

```
$sql .=<<<AZE
where convert(NumberID, char(20)) like '%{$search_term}%'
AZE;
```

The trick is to cast NumberID to string. Casting the right side of 'like' to string  is nonsense.